# twitter follow button not showing

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to integrate a twitter follow button to my web application. i create a DOM element for twitter follow button and append to the body and it works fine.I want to show the twitter follow button in a particular div.

I create the DOM elememt like that.

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    var social_likes = document.createElement('div');
    social_likes.id = 'social_like';
    document.body.appendChild(social_likes);

    var twitter = document.createElement('a');
    twitter.setAttribute("href", "http://twitter.com/TwitterDev");
    twitter.setAttribute("class", "twitter-follow-button");
    twitter.setAttribute("data-size", "large");
    twitter.setAttribute("data-show-count", "false");
    twitter.setAttribute("data-show-screen-name", "false");
    document.getElementById("social_like").appendChild(twitter);
```

And twitter javascript SDK

```
  window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = {
    _e: [],
    ready: function(f) {
    t._e.push(f)
   }
  });

  }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
  twttr.ready(function(twttr) {
   twttr.events.bind('follow', function(e) {
    alert("FOLLOW!");
  });
 });
```

I'm facing that same issue on facebook like button and i'm using `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fb-root'));` that i resolve the problem.

I'm using the iframe tag instead of a tag it shows within a div like

```
<iframe
 src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?
 screen_name=TwitterDev&show_screen_name=false&show_count=false&size=l"
 title="Follow TwitterDev on Twitter"
 width="80"
 height="30"
 style="border: 0; overflow: hidden;"
 ></iframe>
```

But i want to the callback after twitter follow button click.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization

Answer (score 1):

By reading through your code, it seems like you are trying to use an inexistent id. The id of the div element is 'social_like' and not 'social_plugin'.

Maybe you could try changing the line:

```
document.getElementById("social_plugin").appendChild(twitter);
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("social_like").appendChild(twitter);
```

You might be able to debug your error more easily by using the DevTools / JS Console on your browser. Does it show any error?

Comment: Sorry to point that again but there's still a spelling mistake there. The id you assigned to the <div> element is "social_like" and not "social_likes".